# Getting new coordinates based on merged table number

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables. One is the base table containing 'table info' for a visitor center. The other contains 'occupations info'.

Base table structure has original coordinates (x,y) recorded for each of the table. However during occupations, a table or two can be merged with another. In such cases, I want to get distinct table list with new coordinates. Base table coordinates can't be changed or updated.

Somehow I am just not getting to the results. You may notice that table number 7 and 9 are merged. 7 is merged into 9. Thus 9 is main table and both table 7 and 9 must have the coordinates of 9.

```
TABLE_NUMBER    T_TABLE     TABLE_TYPE  LOCATION_X  LOCATION_Y
1                (null)     Rectangular     49      74
2                (null)     Rectangular     68      101
3                3          Rectangular     49      107
4                4          Rectangular     24      80
5                (null)     Rectangular     82      80
6                6          Round           29      19
7                (null)     Round           13      9
8                8          Round           66      10
9                9          Round           112     16
9                7          Round           112     16
```

---

Expected results:

```
TABLE_NUMBER    TABLE_TYPE    LOCATION_X    LOCATION_Y
 1               Rectangular    49           74
 2               Rectangular    68           101
 3               Rectangular    49           107
 4               Rectangular    24           80
 5               Rectangular    82           80
 6               Round          29           19
 7               Round          112          16
 8               Round          66           10
 9               Round          112          16
```

### Here's the [sql fiddle for reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e42c7/2).

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, and what are the results you should be getting (you shouldn't rely solely on SQL Fiddle to store this information)?  (as a side note, I originally though `TABLE` referred to a **db-table**, and thought this was going to need some monster dynamic sql.  #whew#.  The things I've seen people try....)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse `what have you tried so far and what are the results you should be getting (you shouldn't rely solely on SQL Fiddle to store this information)?` you and I both been in SO for awhile and I usually make sure the queations I ask are upto the *minimum standard at least*. If one reads the question, one can notice my expected results. What do you mean by don't solely depend on SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works. [Fiddle Attached](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e42c7/13)

**Script:**

```
;WITH cte_temp AS
(
  SELECT TT.TABLE_NUMBER
      ,TC.TABLE_NUMBER T_TABLE
      ,TT.[TABLE_TYPE]
      ,TT.[LOCATION_X]
      ,TT.[LOCATION_Y]      
  FROM [TABLES] TT LEFT JOIN [OCCUPATIONS] TC
  ON (TT.[TABLE_NUMBER] = CASE WHEN TC.[MAIN_TABLE_NUMBER] = 0 THEN TC.TABLE_NUMBER
  ELSE TC.MAIN_TABLE_NUMBER END)
)

SELECT DISTINCT 
      a.TABLE_NUMBER,
      a.TABLE_TYPE,
      CASE WHEN a.T_TABLE IS NULL AND b.T_TABLE IS NOT NULL THEN b.LOCATION_X ELSE a.LOCATION_X END AS LOCATION_X,
      CASE WHEN a.T_TABLE IS NULL AND b.T_TABLE IS NOT NULL THEN b.LOCATION_Y ELSE a.LOCATION_Y END AS LOCATION_Y
FROM cte_temp AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_temp AS b
    ON a.TABLE_NUMBER = b.T_TABLE
```

Comment: In your concept, a temp table has to be created. Althought I appreciate your attemp, I wish if we could get the results using only the original tables. What do you think?

Comment: @bonCodigo, I have modified the query as per you fiddle. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh. But I don't see much difference between the results you have gotten using a `CTE` compared to my original results. Further, the Table number `9` repeats... What do you suggest? I need high portability for my code - so having a CTE, shouldn't there a second thought to consider?

Comment: Thats quite alright, I see that you have modified your question so my result was based on my understanding on what was posted yesterday. I should have checked the Question again before I jumped in and modified my query and that's on me. Let me go through your question and try and see how I can assist. :)

Comment: As for the CTE, its kind of like a view with the exception of not having a cached execution plan. Once we have the logic ironed out, there are other options you can consider that can replace the CTE. I find it easier to explain and present using CTE as the logic and be spread out.

Comment: @bonCodigo, I have added new fiddle.

Comment: @bonCodigo, did the changes to the query give the expected result.

Comment: I am accepting the answer as a matter of courtesy and to acknowledge your efforts. However *I would appreciate a plain query - if possible*. :) You seem to be very excited to answer in your first phase of SO - keep it up.

Comment: @bonCodigo, Appreciate it.